# Xcode 10 test failure when running on older iOS simulators - "Failed to load test bundle... no suitable image found"

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcode10, ios12

I've installed Xcode 10 and upgraded my iOS application to Swift 4.2. When I run my tests (both UI and Unit) via Xcode, on an iPhone simulator running iOS 12, the tests successfully start. When I attempt to run the tests on a simulator running a prior iOS version (e.g. iOS 10.3.1), I get a "failure to load the test bundle". These tests were running successfully on Xcode 9.4. I can run my app on this older simulator without an issue.

The Xcode output is as follows ("Reading List" is the application name):

> 2018-09-16 15:11:36.667 ReadingList[11401:11478426] Failed to load test bundle from file:///Users/andrewbennet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReadingList-edsxqugqvkymbgfrbivbjmzebuya/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReadingList.app/PlugIns/ReadingList_UnitTests.xctest/: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "dlopen_preflight(/Users/andrewbennet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReadingList-edsxqugqvkymbgfrbivbjmzebuya/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReadingList.app/PlugIns/ReadingList_UnitTests.xctest/ReadingList_UnitTests): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /Users/andrewbennet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReadingList-edsxqugqvkymbgfrbivbjmzebuya/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReadingList.app/PlugIns/ReadingList_UnitTests.xctest/ReadingList_UnitTests: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Users/andrewbennet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReadingList-edsxqugqvkymbgfrbivbjmzebuya/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReadingList.app/PlugIns/ReadingList_UnitTests.xctest/ReadingList_UnitTests, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Users/andrewbennet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReadingList-edsxqugqvkymbgfrbivbjmzebuya/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReadingList.app/PlugIns/ReadingList_UnitTests.xctest/ReadingList_UnitTests): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /Users/andrewbennet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReadingList-edsxqugqvkymbgfrbivbjmzebuya/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReadingList.app/PlugIns/ReadingList_UnitTests.xctest/ReadingList_UnitTests: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator, NSBundlePath=/Users/andrewbennet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReadingList-edsxqugqvkymbgfrbivbjmzebuya/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReadingList.app/PlugIns/ReadingList_UnitTests.xctest, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “ReadingList_UnitTests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.}

The line `mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator` seems like it could be key. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Something similar happen to me, I was not able to run the tests using the command line. What it worked for me was cleaning the delvery data folder so there is no need to change the iOS versions that your apps supports

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The test targets had the `iOS Deployment Target` setting left as the default value.

In Xcode 9.4, this is equal to "iOS 11.4", yet the tests can still be run on an "iPhone 7 (10.3)" simulator for some reason. In Xcode 10, there seems to be a change in behaviour since the tests no longer run on simulators running iOS versions prior to the default "iOS 12".

Comment: I had a [very similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56259572/swift-ui-tests-failing-to-launch-on-pre-ios-12-3-devices) where my UI tests would run fine on any simulator but not on a device with iOS less than 12.3. Turns out that the UI tests deployment target was set to the default of iOS 12 and I'd only changed the app-under-test's deployment target to iOS 10. When I made the UI tests target deployment target to iOS 10 it started running fine on device too.

Comment: Absolute life saver!

Answer (score 5):

In the Project Navigator, select the project file.
Select the Target in the Project configuration window.
Select Build Settings tab, (Basic and Levels)
Scroll down to iOS Deployment Target and then select the desired OS version.

That solved the problem for me.
cheers
rgds Dave